# SPFX - Target Audiences

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, audience-targeting

what do you know about target audiences in Spfx modern pages or webparts?

i have been searching information about this, but I'm still in blank.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

SPFx does not support audience targeting.